# Finding the vertices of a square giving the mid point and radius

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I'm a programmer with terrible mathematics skills, but I'm getting by with studies. I'm trying to find out the vertices `(x,y)` of a square, giving the `centre point (0,0)` and the `radius` of the square which is `0.5`.

Is there a formula that can locate `A, B, C` and `D`?

```
void Draw(int s) //pass in S for numberof sides 
{


    const unsigned int sides = s; //number of siders

    const float PI = 3.14159; //pie 
    const float step = (2 * PI) / static_cast<float>(sides); //make the circle and divide it by the amount of sides to get the shape 

    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);//the x and y position of the shape 
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);//the angle, we spin on Z axis, also set point
    glScalef(radius, radius, 0);//depending on the radius it scales the shape 

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);//we tell gl we make triangle fan 
    glVertex2f(0, 0);//start from this point 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= sides; ++i)//depending on how many sides we have, loop it 
    {
        if (i == 0)
            glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);//make sure the first shape changes colour
        else if (i == 1)
            glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);//leave the other triangles red
        else
            glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);//leave the other triangles red


        glVertex2f(cos(i * step), sin(i * step));//Returns the cosine of the specified angle
        v[i].x = cos(i * step);
        v[i].y = cos(i * step);
        cout << v[i].x << endl;
        //makes the lines, starts from 




    }
    glEnd();//tell open gl we finish making shape 


}
```

[image]

As you can see from the code it creates a shape depending on the number of sides. Four sides will amount to a square. However, how can I get the vertices of the square.

This is because I want to morph the pentagon into the square by interpolating it, with the code provided that makes the square, I do not now how I can get the vertices of the square.

Comment: What do you mean by the "radius" of the square: the radius of the incircle, the circumcircle, or something else? Also, do you assume that the sides of the square are parallel to the axes? If not, there are infinitely many answers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I have made edits to my question.

Comment: You have not answered my questions. The code used the variable "radius" in one line that is unclear since it just calls another routine. So what does "radius" mean? Your picture shows the square's sides at a 45 degree angle with the axes: is that what you want?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sorry, radius is a variable that scales the square. The only line that uses radius is 'glScalef(radius, radius, 0);//' The square is okay, how it is. I want to calculate the vertices of the square. The mid point is '(0,0)', I just need to find 'A','B','C', and 'D'.